# Sum everything in dynamic cell - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript code that generates html table and fill the info in it taken from the text areas. I want to show the total of specific cell each time the button is clicked for new product (the new value - price to be added in the total). In few words, the sum of all products to be shown. The same thing when deleting the specific cell, it needs to be removed from the total.

Now this works fine until i enter different number...

Also see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBVW2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow(formID, tableID) {              
             var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var form = document.forms[formID];
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);                
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = form.elements['product'].value;
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell4.name = "pricee";
            cell4.id = "pricee";                
            cell4.innerHTML = form.elements['price'].value;             
            // ******************** Important part ******************************
            var tot=0; 
            for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){    
                tot += parseInt(cell4.innerHTML,10);        
            }
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=tot;
            // ******************** Important part ******************************
        }
        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body><form id="fid">
Total:      <span name="total" id="total"></span><br/>                      
Product:      <br/><input type="text" id="product"/><br/>
Price:  <br/><input type="text" id="price"/><br/>
<INPUT type="button" value="add" id="add" onclick="addRow('fid','dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="delete" id="delete" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="auto" border="1">
    <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD>id</TD>
<TD>product</TD>
    <TD>price</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tot=0; 
for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){    
    tot += parseInt(cell4.innerHTML,10);        
}
```

In the above piece of code, *you're not iterating the row but **referring only to the last column.***

So on each iteration, the last column value is getting added.

Instead try below code

```
var tot=0; 
for(var i=1;i<=rowCount;i++){
    tot += parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML,10);       
}
```

Here I have used `i = 1` because `0` represents the heading `tr` and to get the price column I have used

```
                    |---------------------3rd column 
table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML
           |__row index
```

---

Similar in *delete* method you have to do the same in reverse  fashion like

```
var tot = +document.getElementById("total").innerHTML; // get total
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        tot -= parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML, 10) //only for checked row
        table.deleteRow(i);  
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = tot;  // update the total
}
```

Check this in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBVW2/4/)

Comment: Thank you, it's working and i understand things a lot better now.

Comment: @BombaRuLz I'm glad I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You made a few mistakes.

Firstly, let me just make it clear that there are certain part I used jQuery, coz I'm not that familiar with javascript syntax.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/caL5p/1/

First mistake:
You used: `cell4.id = "pricee";`
This is wrong. Id cannot be repeated, and hence your result will always add the last number * the amount of rows you have. If you were to alert `parseInt(cell4.innerHTML,10);`, you'll find out what I mean.

This is what you should do instead.
`cell4.setAttribute('class',"pricee");`

For the rest, refer to the code in the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for this  but i'm not allowed to use js libraries in the project, it's not up to me :) It looks easy by the way, i'll start learning jquery in a month. Cheers

Comment: sure. I used libraries to be a little lazy. :)